# Combining Data from two columns in excel, alternate rows

Tags: excel-formula

I have two columns A and B

```
**A**     
30   
40    
50    
60    
70   

**B**
90
80
10
20
```

I am struggling to find a formula that will allow me to combine the two columns by taking first value of column A followed by two values of column B and so on:

Combined Column "C" Example:

```
**C**
30
90
80
40
10
20
and so on.
```

What can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data starts from row 1, you can type the following formula in column C:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=1,INDIRECT("A"&TEXT(ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0),"0")),IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=2,INDIRECT("B"&TEXT(ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0)*2-1,"0")),INDIRECT("B"&TEXT(ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0)*2,"0"))))
```

If the data starts from row 2, then the formula is:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=2,INDIRECT("A"&TEXT(ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0)+1,"0")),IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=0,INDIRECT("B"&TEXT(ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0)*2,"0")),INDIRECT("B"&TEXT(ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0)*2-1,"0"))))
```

Comment: how should this be changed to have it start on the second row?Sorry, I am having trouble adapting the formula.

Comment: @cpott I've edited the answer and added the formula for data start from row 2.